# How can i define a fixed html Type on fulltext index

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a column `content` of type `varbinary(max)`, which always contain `html` content.

How can I define a fulltext index on that column of type `.html` without having to create another column `ContentType` and always store `.html`?

For example, here I have to define TYPE COLUMN:

```sql
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Documents
(
    [Content] TYPE COLUMN ContentType
)
KEY INDEX PK_Documents ON ft_catalog
```

I tried to break the syntax here from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) by doing this which did not do the job:

```sql
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Documents
(
    [Content] TYPE '.html'
)
KEY INDEX PK_Documents ON ft_catalog
```

Comment: Computed non-persisted column?

Comment: @Charlieface interesting! Thanks!!